# Let $\mathcal{M}(\Xi)$ set of all probability destributions on $\Xi$. Supremum over $\mathcal{M}(\Xi)$ is equal to sup over Dirac distributions

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, dirac-operator

This doubt is born because I am reading an article in this [link in pag 12](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.05116.pdf) in order to use these ideas to prove another problem that raised me. My doubt is following:

Let $(\Xi,\mathcal{E})$ be a measurable space and $\mathbb{Q}_{i}$ measures in this space and $\xi_{i}\in\Xi$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,N.$ Let $f:\Xi\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function.

**The question:** I need show that 
$$\sup_{\mathbb{Q}_{i}\in\mathbb{M}(\Xi)}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Xi}f(\xi-\xi_{i})\mathbb{Q}_{i}(d\xi)\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sup_{\xi\in\Xi}f(\xi-\xi_{i})$$
where $\mathcal{M}(\Xi)$ is the set of all probability distributions  supported on $\Xi$

**My attempt:** The first thing I thought is this
\begin{align}
\sup_{\mathbb{Q}_{i}\in\mathbb{M}(\Xi)}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Xi}f(\xi-\xi_{i})\mathbb{Q}_{i}(d\xi)\right] &= \sup\left\{\left.\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Xi}f(\xi-\xi_{i})\mathbb{Q}_{i}(d\xi)  \right| \mathbb{Q}_{i}\in\mathcal{M}(\Xi) \mbox{ for }i=1,\ldots,N \right\} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sup\left\{\left.\int_{\Xi}f(\xi-\xi_{i})\mathbb{Q}_{i}(d\xi)  \right| \mathbb{Q}_{i}\in\mathcal{M}(\Xi) \right\}\\
(1)\qquad &\geq \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sup\left\{\left.\int_{\Xi}f(\zeta-\xi_{i})\delta_{\xi}(d\zeta)  \right| \xi\in\Xi  \right\}  \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sup_{\xi\in\Xi}f(\xi-\xi_{i})
\end{align}

where $(1)$ follows from the fact that $\mathcal{M}(\Xi)$ contains all the Dirac distributions supported on $\Xi$.

The **probblem is the inequality $\leq$**, **I need a suggestion to prove this inequality.**

Comment: What does $\xi - \xi_i$ mean? Is $\Xi$ a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attempt you made to prove inequality $ \leq $ is correct. The other desiguladad is consequence of the following general fact:

> For every fixed function $g$ and every probability distribution $\mu$,
>   $$\int_Xgd\mu\leqslant\sup_X g\cdot\mu(X)=\sup_Xg$$